# What do you mean by bifurcation of the following equations/systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, bifurcation

I am new to the domain of **bifurcation**. I encounter the following problems:

Analyze the bifurcation of the following equations/systems. Identify the bifurcation values(s), describe the bifurcation and sketch the bifurcation diagram where appropriate.

$\bullet \frac{dx}{dt} = ax+a-1.$

$\bullet \frac{dx}{dt} = x +ay,  \frac{dy}{dt} = (a+3)x+ay.$

---

Can someone give me some reference where I can look up for these type of problems? Or help me in doing these?

Thank You.

Comment: see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC2w2z_i2DA) for the bifurcation diagram

Comment: Or you might try [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Equations-Tools-Printed-Access/dp/1133109039/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=differential+equations+with&qid=1620711333&sr=8-4). Birfurcation of the first form is discussed in 1.7, the second one (which is a bifurcation of linear system) is discussed in 3.7